# Sqlboiler get only the desired columns

Tags: sql, go, orm

I am trying to follow the examples in sqlboiler (https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler). But couldn't find a way to get just the columns queried in the select statement?

```
users, err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
).All(ctx, db)
```

In this example, `.All` returns entire tuple containing empty/nil values of columns not queried. I was wondering if there is a way to return a map/list (or any relevant data structure/format) of just the queried columns. Thanks!

Comment: I believe your question has been answered, even if it's not quite as convenient as some might like.  Would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You get all the fields, because you get instances of `models.User`, which have all the fields, you want them or not.

One thing you can do is write your own cut-down `User` struct, and bind to that.

```golang
type LiteUser struct {
  ID int `boil:"id"`
  Name string `boil:"name"`
}

var users []*LiteUser
err := models.Users(
  Select("id", "name"),
  Where("age > ?", 30),
).Bind(ctx, db, &users)
```

Comment: Yikes, the select should work here without the LiteUser struct but I guess it don't work

Comment: Use a map instead of a struct, my guess